# Make ProFTPD only auth against MySQL (no PAM)

Tags: mysql, ftp, authentication, proftpd

I have successfully setup ProFTPD to use mod_sql for authentication. But I can still login with linux user's credentials, even though I've set `AuthPAM off`. How can I make ProFTPD to not use PAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both AuthPAM and AuthOrder, like this:

```
AuthOrder       mod_sql.c
AuthPAM         off
```

Answer (score 2):

Try restricting authentication to just sql

`AuthOrder mod_sql.c`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
AuthPAMAuthoritative            off
```

Comment: `Fatal: unknown configuration directive 'AuthPAMAuthoritative'`. Which is weird, the docs says it should exist from 1.2.0pre3. I'm using 1.3.2